# query to color rows not read by another color in datatable jsf2 and primefaces

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I have this method that return me a List that load my datatable :

```
public List<Message> getMessagesRecues(Integer idUser) {
    List<Message> cs = null;
    try {

        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("alors : "+idUser);
        Query q = session.createQuery("select c.message from Destinataire c where c.utilisateur.id='"+idUser+"'");

        if(q.list().size() > 0)
        cs = q.list();

        session.clear();
        session.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return cs;
}
```

this method works well
in the database the table is like this : [image: table in database]

I work with netbeans and hibernate, 
and my goal is I want to color the rows that have c.lu = false by a red color or put the writing in bold , but I don't know how to get the information from database and loading in datatable (I work with jsf2 and primefaces)

here is my datatable :

```
 <p:dataTable id="carsTables" var="car1" value="#{histMessagesController.lm_r}" rowKey="#{car.id}"  rowStyleClass="#{(car.lu == false) ? 'red' : null}"   >

                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    Historique des messages recus
                                </f:facet>

                                <p:column style="width:48%">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        Titre
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car1.titre}" escape="false" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column style="width:48%">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        Date de Création
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car1.dateEnvoi}" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column >                              
                                    <p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":myform:carDlg" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">  
                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car1}" target="#{histMessagesController.selectedMessage}" />  
                                    </p:commandButton>                              
                                </p:column>  


                            </p:dataTable>
```

how I can achieve this, thank you very much

Comment: How are your entities annotated/mapped?

Comment: my entities are mapped with hibernate mapping files and pojos wizart in netbeabns and (in general setting I used jdk5 langage feature so they are mapped)

Comment: You need to somehow navigate from car to destinataire. If your car entity has a destinataire entity, you can simply call `Car.getDestinataire.getLu()`.

Comment: How are you filling the table? looks like you are using a lm_r method in your controller and not the getMessagesRecues that you are showing. Also have you defined the 'red' css class that you are mentioning?? and lastly... you are making reference to a var named 'car' when you should use 'car1' in the (car.lu == false) sentence

Answer (score 0):

try setting the outcome of the `rowStyleClass` attribute on your datatable to resolve to a string outcome instead of the boolean i.e. `rowStyleClass=#{car1.lu}` and then in a separate css stylesheet have `.true td:nth-child(1) input {
    background-color: green;
}

.false td:nth-child(1) input {
    background-color: red;
}`

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743258/1530938

for more clarity

Comment: You're also referencing the wrong row var as @Lando mentioned in the comment above. This might as well be the source of the problem